# jquery animate left with fixed loading div

Tags: jquery

I know this is supposed to be simple but i cant figure out what is wrong.
I am using fixed div at left-bottom corner to display loading/spinner div.

Loader should slide from left to right when it is shown (initially it is set to display:none;).
On Hide it should slide from right to left and disappear.

[**JSFIDDLE Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/R28rm/4/)

**CSS**

```
#loading span {
    float:left;
    margin-top :1px;
    margin-left :3px;
    margin-right :3px;
    line-height:16px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"oswald";
}
#loading img {
    float:left;
    margin-top : 1px;
}
#loading {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000000;
    left:0;
    top:90% !important;
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" id="sh">Show!</button>
<button type="button" id="hd">Hide!</button>

<div id="loading"><span> loading </span>
    <img class="loader" src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" width="16" height="16" />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
// Show loading 
$('#sh').on('click', function () {
     $("#loading")
         .animate({
             left: -160
         }, {
             duration: 'slow',
             easing: 'easeOutBounce'
         })
         .animate({
             left: 0
         }, {
             duration: 'slow',
             easing: 'easeOutBounce'
         })
         .show();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sh').on('click', function () {
     $("#loading").toggle('Bounce');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wWnrS/

You could use hide and show aswell, just like that:

```
$('#sh').on('click', function () {
     $("#loading").show('Bounce');
 });
```

Comment: `toggle()` doesn't have a built in `Bounce` effect, but any string will make it default to 600ms, and that's why you get the animation, which is nothing like the one in the question, check out this one -> http://jsfiddle.net/wWnrS/1/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put both the hide code and the show code inside the callback for the show button. Instead of

```
// Show loading 
$('#sh').on('click', function () {
     $("#loading")
         .animate({
         left: -160
     }, {
         duration: 'slow',
         easing: 'easeOutBounce'
     })
         .animate({
         left: 0
     }, {
         duration: 'slow',
         easing: 'easeOutBounce'
     }).show();

 });

// Hide loading 
$('#sh').on('click', function () {
  });
```

You want

```
// Show loading 
$('#hd').on('click', function () {
     $("#loading")
         .animate({
         left: -160
     }, {
         duration: 'slow',
         easing: 'easeOutBounce'
     })

 });

// Hide loading 
$('#sh').on('click', function () {
     $("#loading")
         .animate({
         left: 0
     }, {
         duration: 'slow',
         easing: 'easeOutBounce'
     }).show();

  });
```

I would suggest, however, that you use the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/%E2%80%8E) function, with `direction: right` instead as it would simplify your code and interface (you probably only want one button, not two).

Comment: u mean direction: right from UI ? I tried it first but on fixed div it behaves strangely,cuts off portion of div with flicker ..

Comment: This works.But Problem is on first run, it shows flatly without easing, after that it works as it should.How can i fix that ? see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/wWnrS/2/) here.

Comment: Fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWnrS/16/ . If you want to see it slide in, you need to start with it visible and off screen (-160px), not `display: none`. So all I did was change those two css lines. Sorry it took so long. I trust you'll accept my answer now?